# Is it possible to pretty print any value/type in clang?

Tags: c++, clang

I often want to inspect some types like integer_sequences, tuples etc while doing metaprogramming and it is cumbersome to implement a print function for every type.

Is it possible to output any value or type with clang? Something like `___message(something)`?

```
using is = std::index_sequence<0,1,2,3>;
___message(is)
//prints: std::integer_sequence<size_t,0,1,2,3>

auto tuple = make_tuple(1,2,3);
___message(tuple)
//prints: std::tuple<int,int,int>(1,2,3)
```

Comment: Interesting. Visual Studio compiler provides kind of pretty names for `typeid(T).name()`. Both clang and gcc is not that pretty.